# How to decide whether to use newCachedThreadPool or newFixedThreadPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am working on a project in which I need to make sure each thread is working on a particular range. For example:

```
NO_OF_THREADS: 2
NO_OF_TASKS: 10
```

If `number of threads is 2` and `number of tasks is 10` then each thread will be performing `10 tasks`. So that means 2 thread will be doing `20 tasks`.

**In actual scenario these numbers (number of tasks and number of threads) will be very high as both of them are configurable in my code.**

In the above example, `first thread` should be using id between `1 and 10` and `second thread` should be using id between `11 and 20` and so on if any more threads. And after that each thread will make a database connection and then insert into database.

So I have my below code which is working fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int noOfThreads = 2;
    final int noOfTasks = 10;

    //create thread pool with given size 
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

    // queue some tasks 
    for (int i = 0, int nextId = 1; i < noOfThreads; i++, nextId += noOfTasks) {
        service.submit(new ThreadTask(nextId, noOfTasks));
    }
}

class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private final int id;
    private int noOfTasks;

    public ThreadTask(int nextId, int noOfTasks) {
        this.id = nextId;
        this.noOfTasks = noOfTasks;
    }

    public void run() {

    //make a database connection

        for (int i = id; i < id + noOfTasks; i++) {

        //insert into database
        }
    }
}
```

**My question:-**

I was going through various article on the internet and I read about `newCachedThreadPool`. So now I am wondering is - Should I use `newFixedThreadPool` or `newCachedThreadPool` in my code? As currently I am using `nexFixedThreadPool`. I am not able to decide on what factors should I choose `newCachedThreadPool` or `newFixedThreadPool`. So that is the reason I posted my scenario what I am going to do with my code.

Can anyone help me out what should I be choosing here? And please explain me in details why we are choosing that on what factors so that I can understand this very well. I have already gone through java docs but not able to decide what should I choose here.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> So now I am wondering is - Should I use newFixedThreadPool or newCachedThreadPool in my code?

To quote from the Javadocs, the `newFixedThreadPool()`:

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads...

This means that if you ask for 2 threads, it will start 2 threads and never start 3.  On the other hand, the `newCachedThreadPool()`:

> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available.

In your case, if you only have 2 thread to run, either will work fine since you will only be submitting 2 jobs to your pool.  However, if you wanted to submit all 20 jobs at once but only have 2 jobs running at one time, you should use a `newFixedThreadPool(2)`.  If you used a cached pool then each of the 20 jobs will start a thread which will run at the same time which may not be optimal depending on how many CPUs you have.

Typically I use the `newCachedThreadPool()` when I *need* the thread to be spawned immediately, even if all of the threads currently running are busy.  I recently used it when I was spawning timer tasks.  The number of concurrent jobs are immaterial because I never spawn very many but I want them to run when they are requested and I want them to re-use dormant threads.

I used `newFixedThreadPool()` when I want to limit the number of concurrent tasks running at any one point to maximize performance and not swamp my server.  For example if I am processing 100k lines from a file, one line at a time, I don't want each line to start a new thread but I want some level of concurrency so I allocate (for example) 10 fixed threads to run the tasks until the pool is exhausted.

Comment: Thanks gray for the suggestion. But that number of threads and number of tasks is configurable in my code. So that means I can run the same program with 100 threads and 10000 number of tasks or any other numbers as well. So what should I be using in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it is highly dependent on the type of job,
If you have a function which is I/O bound, use newCachedThreadPool()
if its a cpu intensive operation without I/O , use the other one.

Comment: If a question is 8 years old and already has an accepted answer, especially a highly upvote one, it is rarely useful to post another reply.