# How to chose an Executor for CompletableFuture::supplyAsync

Tags: java, java-8, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, completable-future

`CompletableFuture::supplyAsync(() -> IO bound queries)`

How do I chose an Executor for CompletableFuture::supplyAsync to avoid polluting the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`.

There are many options in `Executors` (`newCachedThreadPool`, `newWorkStealingPool`, `newFixedThreadPool` etc)

And I read about new ForkJoinPool [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream)

How do I chose the right one for my use case ?

Comment: if the number of concurrent queries is going to be limited you can use a cached thread pool - if there's a chance that the number could be very high (several 100s or 1000s or more) you can use a fixed thread pool with a reasonable limit. The answer depends on your use case and parameters (memory, OS etc.).

Comment: Here is the best article I have ever read about Executors, from Jessica Kerr: http://blog.jessitron.com/2014/01/choosing-executorservice.html - You should read it.

Comment: Nice article , thanks @Ruban. I am using AWS lambda as the compute engine and I have 1536MB of memory and I am not doing any recursive computation , so that eliminates ForkJoinPool. Based on that flow diagram, I guess CachedThreadPool is the most appropriate for my use case.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949355/newcachedthreadpool-v-s-newfixedthreadpool and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058978/how-to-decide-whether-to-use-newcachedthreadpool-or-newfixedthreadpool

Comment: Just use the default one (common FJP). If you have problems with such approach, ask new question specifying exact problems you have. If you don't have problems, that's nice.

Comment: Why not use the common pool? If you create executors you will just pollute the OS with threads. The only reason is if the task will sleep/busy wait. Is that what you mean by "IO bound queries"? The parallelism will be  `(availableProcessors-1)` in most cases. So another option would be to set `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` to a higher value. But that might slow down some uses of the common pool.

Comment: Something else to consider is that you can not shut down the common pool. So if you ever might need that you should use your own `Executor`.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier, Executor executor)` method. 
As executor you can use any from the Executors.new.. - it depends on your needs.
It's better to use newFixedThreadPool() rather than newCachedThreadPool(), since newCachedThreadPool() can lead to performance issues creating to many threads or even throw OutOfMemoryError. 
Here's a very nice [article](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/) with good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Anton's Answer, it is wise to use newFixedThreadPool rather than newCachedThreadPool unless you know the operation will not cause OutOfMemoryError. Since, your request is an i/o process the usage of Async nio request such as AsynchronousFileChannel or Async Rest Client...etc could greatly supplement your performance.