# Define number of threads in Java

Tags: java

On application, i'm using 
`Executor executionContext = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);`
for fixed the 10 threads.

I don't want to fix the number of thread, **I want thread will be dynamic**. The number of threads it requires, it will process.
How it can be applied?

Comment: see the code http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java.html , I think you are looking for newCachedThreadPool()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decide whether to use newCachedThreadPool or newFixedThreadPool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058978/how-to-decide-whether-to-use-newcachedthreadpool-or-newfixedthreadpool)

Answer (score 0):

The 10 in your question is the value of the thread pool, not the number of threads. You say that you want:

> The number of threads it requires, it will process.

Then your code will work as you want. It will use as many threads as it needs until it reaches the thread pool value. You can also choose what happens when it reaches the max thread pool using "rejection policy".